# How can I required one field out of two when using jQuery Validation with Unobtrusive

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-core-3.0

I have an app that is written on the top of ASP.NET Core 3. My project use [jQuery.Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) and [jQuery.Validation-Unobtrusive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

I have a form that required either `Phone` or `Email` fields. My form is also using the input-mask to force the user to type in a valid US-phone number or email.

Here is how I configured my form-validation

```
$('#ScheduleTourForm').validate({
    ignore: "",
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        Day: {
            required: true,  // require date
            date: true,      // value must be a datetime value
        },
        Time: {
            required: true,  // require time
            date: true,      // value must be a datetime value
        },
        Phone: {
            required: '#Email:blank',  // Only require Phone if Email is blank
            phoneUS: true              // US-phone format is required
        },
        Email: {
            required: function (e) {
                var p = $("#Phone");
                return p.is(':empty') || p.val() === '(___) ___-____'; // Only require email when Phone is empty or has the default mask.
            },
            email: true // must be a valid email
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        console.log('submit form...');

        //$(form).ajaxSubmit();
    }

});
```

However, that does not seems to be requiring nither the Phone or the Email. An example of the code not working can be found on this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0fod4cj/)

How can I correctly require either `Phone` or `Email`?

Comment: You cannot use the Unobtrusive Validation plugin AND initialize the plugin with a your own call to `.validate()`.  The whole point of the Unobtrusive plugin is that it picks up your inline data attributes and constructs the `.validate()` method for you.  Since the validation plugin ignores duplicate calls to this method, it's ignoring your call to `.validate()`.  Secondly, there is a rule called `require_from_group` that does what you want and it's part of the `additional-methods.js` file.

Comment: Is it possible to use unobtrusive to ensure at least one field is required?

Comment: AFAIK, `require_from_group` cannot be implemented or configured via data attributes, so if you're using Unobtrusive, I don't see how.